# i have student db in my localhost but still it showing this

Tags: rmysql

```
install.packages("RMySQL")
library(RMySQL)
library(dbConnect)
install.packages("dbConnect", type = "source")
library(dbConnect)
mysqlconnection = dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'root', password = '', dbname = 'student', host = 'localhost')
```

Error in .local(drv, ...) :    Failed to connect to database: Error: Unknown database 'student':

Comment: try to connect to that database from a different client, with the same username and password - do you see the 'student' database? If not, this is what the error message tells you. You nee to create the database first.

Comment: First things first. Please Read how to ask a question and format Code related stuff to improve reading. Die you Tex to Add Standard Port 3306 for your Connection? Can you give us more information about the db. Ja oh a Server or docker Container?

Comment: @Y.L yes i am able to see the database student from cmd and also from phpmyadmin and aslo from other clients

Answer (score 0):

mysqlconnection = dbConnect(MySQL(), user = 'root', password = '', dbname = 'student',
                            port = 3308)
dbListTables(mysqlconnection)